# Quarkus Jax-rs clients with external interfaces

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I started playing around with Quarkus and its REST client. According to the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client) a Jax-RS annotated interface should be created and annotated further with @RegisterRestClient.

My issue is that I already have the JaxRS interfaces for the services I need to connect to, in an artifact provided by the server, which I can just import. Is there a way to use an already created external Jax-RS interface to create a service with? It seems so wrong to copy-paste the code for a perfectly good interface, when it has been so nicely served for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `RestClientBuilder`, which allows programmatic usage of JAX-RS interfaces. Assuming the JAX-RS interface is called `HelloClient`, you can do this:

```java
HelloClient client = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .baseUri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080"))
    .build(HelloClient.class);
```

Comment: That sounds awesome. Can you be persuaded to update your reply with a way to disable the SSL checks, and even better, add basic auth?